# Segmentation 11 in C trying to recreate Stty

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to edit the settings of my terminal just for kicks. When I press "-a", "LEFT" should appear to the screen. When I press "-w", "UP" should appear on the screen. However, when I executed my program, I get a segmentation 11 error and I want to know why. My code is posted below and if you have any questions, please feel free to ask. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int result = 0;             // result = file descriptor
    struct termios attrib;      // attrib that's going to be messed with
    struct termios sec_attrib;  // attrib that's going to reset everything

    //
    // TURN OFF: ICANON AND ECHO
    // TURN ON: VMIN

    tcgetattr(result, &attrib); //getting the attributes from attrib
    attrib.c_lflag &= ~ICANON; // turn off ICANON
    attrib.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;   // turn off ECHO
    attrib.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    tcsetattr(result, TCSANOW, &attrib);

    int x = 0;
    while(x != -1){
        if(strcmp(argv[1], "-w") == 0){
            printf("UP");
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-a") == 0){
            printf("LEFT");
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-s") == 0){
            printf("DOWN");
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-d") == 0){
            printf("RIGHT");
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-q") == 0){
            x = -1;
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }

    // reset everything
    tcsetattr(result, TCSANOW, &sec_attrib);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I want to know why". The way to find that out is to do proper debugging. And the best way to do that is to run your program in a debugger, trace its execution and examine state. For example, the debugger will tell you immediately and precisely which line of code causes the seg fault.

Comment: Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: `strcmp(argv[1]` That's not correct. The key presses do not come from the command line (which `argv` contains). You need to read `stdin`.

Comment: @kaylum Ahhhh, that makes sense. I did use a debugger and it came up with "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code = 1, address=0x0)"

Comment: Hope you are on the right track now. But really suggest you learn to use the debugger properly. What you have shown is just a tiny tiny fraction of what you can find out from the debugger. Learn the debugger commands: e.g. the command that prints the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be under the impression that reading `argv[1]` reads from the keyboard.  This is not true.  What it does is read the first command line argument given to it, i.e. `argv[1]`.  If you don't pass any arguments, this is an invalid address, and reading it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).